# Why are strawman claims allowed to stand?

Tags: discussion, notability, scope

This question: [Did Bernie Sanders never "earn a steady paycheck" before 40?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/31932/did-bernie-sanders-never-earn-a-paycheck-before-40)

Makes for a nice NHQ fodder, due to the topic.

Except the "claim" it cites is 100% strawman.

The question's "claim" - which is diligently "debunked" by an answer, being a convinient made up strawman - is `Did Bernie Sanders never “earn a paycheck” before 40`

> There is a meme ... didn't "**earn a paycheck**" before the age of 40.
>
> What truth is there to this claim? **Did Bernie Sanders support himself before the age of 40**?

## However, a 3-second check of the 4 links provided to "prove" notability shows that **none of the sources actually make that claim**!

The exact claim - which wasn't mentioned in either the question or the answer - is that he didn't earn a **steady** paycheck.

<sub>I can get onboard with stating that this claim is too vague to be proven or disproven since "steady" is not a precise term. But that is 100% irrelevant to the question and answer as they stand right now</sub>

- Gateway Pundit shows that the claim was different strait in the headline:

  > "Bernie Sanders a Bum Who Didn’t Earn His First **Steady** Paycheck Until Age 40 Then Wormed His Way Into Politics".

  and the body's first sentence:

  > Bernie Sanders was a bum who didn’t earn a **steady** paycheck until he was 40 years old
- Fox News link has the same headline:

  > Bernie Sanders a Bum Who Didn't Earn His First **Steady** Paycheck Until Age 40 Then Wormed His Way Into Politics

  Which makes complete sense since the link wasn't to fox news, it was to their news aggregator, which was linking to the above Gateway Pundit link in the first place.
- American Spectator's headline omits the "steady" term, but just the headline:

  > Bernie Sanders Didn’t Make a Paycheck Until He Turned 40

  But the article's body actually cites the same Investor's Business Daily article as everyone else with actual claim:

  > Despite a prestigious degree, however, Sanders failed to earn a living, even as an adult. It took him 40 years to collect his first **steady** paycheck — and it was a government check.
- Even Crowder is 100% same - loud sensationalist headline, but the body of the article explicitly quotes the same exact correct claim, from the same exact IBD article as the first 3 sources:

  > It took him 40 years to collect his first **steady** paycheck — and it was a government check
  > However, the actual article quotes the original Investor's Business Daily article:

I have seen questions on Skeptics.SE closed instantly before when the claim they made was vastly different from the actual claim in the sources they cited for notability and incorrect.

### So, why was this question positing a strawman claim allowed to stand?

Comment: Nobody flagged it or voted to close so far, independent of whether it should be closed, this is the reason why it isn't closed yet.

Comment: One thing is debating site policy, another is simply reiterating a potentially trite discussion. This question is just assuming intentions and asking for opinions. Furthermore, there's another meta question debating this post by the same author. As such, I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

Original asker here, with a candidate answer. Titles / URLs are more visible text than the article body; they are seen first, more frequently, and they may even be all that is seen. Misleading text here has a disproportionate effect and may set the tone even if you do read the whole article.

Next, is "steady" even a vital piece of this picture? I'd argue that it's not. The message is clearly that Sanders is a bum, whatever language they use to dress it up. Why call into question his ability to earn a paycheck otherwise? The implication is clear. "Steady" in this case is feigned euphemism.

Would I agree with the community's decision to edit the question to say "steady"? No. But I could understand and accept it; in any event, a new question on the more modest claims would be a good one. But to close the question? That would be lazy. There is clearly a claim substantially similar to what is being asked, whether it's exact or not. To imagine that the "notability" threshold exists to screen out this sort of minor shortcoming seems to go too far.

Comment: It's a common user experience practice to format your links with descriptive text. For example http://company.com/article/really-cool-title/ is not as helpful or easy to read as [Really Cool Title - Company](http://company.com/article/really-cool-title/) or [an article on really cool topic](http://company.com/article/really-cool-title/). Just look at this site. You don't see a bunch of unformatted links. You see real words and sentences that are linked to content that relates to those words and sentences.

Comment: @fredsbend A fair observation generally, but it is not a requirement and doing so obscures the claim which I was asking about in this instance. Also, FWIW - it's not like I scoured the Internet for URLs that lacked "steady". Those were the fest or search results. Three out of four URLs agreed - leaving aside whether "steady" makes any real difference at all, as some users seem to think, anyway.

Comment: Like I said before, I don't think the text of a url should be taken seriously compared to the actual article. Those come from headlines, which are often written to draw traffic rather than as descriptors of the article content.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question was problematic, but it wasn't a "blatant strawman" question, which is why it wasn't closed.

I think the order of events is clear:

1. [Investor's Business Daily](http://www.investors.com/politics/editorials/bernie-sanders-the-bum-who-wants-your-money/) published a hatchet opinion piece, referring to "steady paycheck" - a poor term, because it dismisses other legitimate income sources, like being paid for carpentry.
2. Several [churnalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Churnalism) articles were written using the IBD story as their only source. They all seem to have maintained the "steady paycheck" term.
3. Then the headline writers have gotten involved, and in some cases skimmed the article and made a mess of it. Headlines tend not to be written by the original journalist, and they have a bad reputation of confusing the claims.
4. I would hazard a guess that the articles that have "correct" headlines but incorrect URLs are because the headline was originally incorrect, the URL was generated from it, and then the headline was corrected.
5. The question was posted.
6. An answer was given addressing the misleading nature of the original article.
7. Only then did someone highlight the discrepancy between the claims.

So, what should be done about it?

Well, if there are (many) people who have read the confused headline (or the URL) and believe it to be true, then it is notable. (It is also a simple answer!)

However, linking to all the sites that get it "right" seems pointless. Maybe we should cull it down to only those that don't?

Ideally, this question would have been quickly put on hold, and we could have cleaned up the disparity, and decided what the notable question was. However, it quickly received a (highly upvoted) answer that addressed not just the "steady" issue but the deeper "paycheck" issue, making it a little moot. We tend to tread much more carefully when questions have reasonable answers, so as not to waste the effort of the answerer.

If this question was politically motivated, I am having a hard time seeing which "side" of US politics looks good in this debacle.

Comment: I didn't claim it's NHQ bait (I still don't quite understand what makies a post NHQ, except generating many answers). I claimed that it's more problematic because NHQ made it more visible (and gave it more votes so that now "it's highy upvoted" can be used as an excuse not to do anything).

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your answer. I think that you are trying to rationalize an approach that is in stark contrast to moderation approaches taken to a vast majority of other questions on the site, but that's fine, humans can write up justification for anything. Do I need to edit my Meta question to give examples of all the questions that were closed on sight when the claim in the question didn't match the original post? Why is there no need to show that people believe the headline to be true despite the headline not matching the article?

Comment: Re: motivation of the question: I would not assume bad motivation, except that **the flaw in the question NOT been pointed the moment it was posted 2 days ago via a comment; and that comment summarily ignored by OP** without so much as an attempt to edit the true claim into the question. That came 2 days before I asked this Meta (as a minor indicator of who was meant to be seen as bad, see "Fox News" bit. The link doesn't go to Fox News, as I noted, but to Fox-owned link aggregator - something obvious from the URL. Same technique as used in "fox news won right to lie" thing).

Comment: BTW, if you don't think this question is in any way different, i'd be happy to propose several incorrect hatchet job Q&As all of which are based on merely a sensationalist headline not matching the actual claim. How many will you reject before you admit this one is just one of them?

Comment: Sorry about misunderstanding your NHQ position. Still pondering the other comments.

Comment: I'm confused by the third comment, sorry. The [first complaint I see about the claim mismatching](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/31932/did-bernie-sanders-never-earn-a-paycheck-before-40#comment121027_31932) postdates the [first answer](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/31934/23).

Comment: @user5341: I've edited it to clarify why this question was treated differently; I hope it seems less of like a rationalisation, but that is a difficult criticism to refute without making it seem more like a rationalisation.

Comment: I don't know the relative timeline, but I don't see how it's relevant. Just that the comment was posted 2 days ago; plenty of time to fix the question. And had 20 upvotes so it's not like it was an inconsequential lost comment OP likely missed.

Comment: OK, so we are back to Mad Scientist's point from comments of "it already had a quick answer". I understand that it's a valid point, but please note that the answer WAS **also** commented on immediately, pointing out that it didn't address the actual article claims. Also ignored. IMO, the existence of an answer not addressing the actual claim should have zero effect on how the question is treated, especially if it was clearly broadcast to them that they are not addressing the actual claim.

Comment: @user5341 I made an edit to the question just after commenting, which went to review because I'm under 2k rep. I added fox news, instead of the plain link text, out of ignorance. It said fox, that's what I noticed. If that's incorrect then you should edit it.

Comment: I agree with you however. It seems odd that no one really cares that the question had the wrong claim.

Comment: @user5341 I mean, if the claim was wrong, why not edit it yourself? I don't hover around this site 24 hours a day. Unless I'm recalling incorrectly, by the time I came back to the question, it already had a ton of votes - the answer too - so I accepted it and decided to leave it to the community. If there's a strawman it at least partly stands because *you* chose not to edit it.

Comment: @patrick 1. It's generally considered bad form to drastically edit other people's questions retroactively.  2. Editing at this point is irrelevant. Should have been done 2 days ago

Comment: @user5341: It seems to me the conflict between "considered bad form to drastically edit other people's questions retroactively" and "I don't know the relative timeline, but I don't see how it's relevant" is important here. It became bad form to edit this question very quickly - before anyone even noticed there was a problem. By the time we did, it was too late.

Comment: @Oddthinking - You have an option I as a user don't have - to delete the answer (thus making any edits non-retroactive, because there's no existing answer to invalidate).

Comment: @user5341 Some other user edited it since you've been complaining about it. I think a fundamental difference of opinion here is how much difference that one word makes. You're welcome to your opinion but you would do well to be less combative - accusing me of deliberately distorting the claim is unfounded and, frankly, insulting. If you thought the claim was mistaken, you were free to take care of it yourself. That's the SE model - and all edits are "retroactive", not sure what that means to distinguish.

Comment: @user5341: If you see me being harsh, quickly, to a question, closing it shortly after it is asked, it is because once it garners an answer, we are far more reluctant to edit a question in a way that invalidates the effort someone has made in putting forward a (reasonable) answer. That's the case here. By the time the problem was noticed, a well-referenced answer addressing the substance was already garnering up-votes. I'm not inclined to delete that.

Comment: @Patrick87 - the fact that you didn't edit for 2 days despite highly upvoted objection pointing out the issue almost immediately was my basis for assuming deliberation. I apologize for offending you, but this is how the optics looks from the outside. Re: "retroactive", I meant "in a way that invalidates an answer posted prior to the edit".

Comment: @Oddthinking - I guess where we differ majorly is the assessment that the answer does or doesn't address the "substance". Debunking some sensationalized headlines contradicted by the actual post's text is IMHO hardly grounds for a substantial answer - especially since it was openly and clearly pointed out to both OP and answerer that the claim being discussed in the posts is different. ...

Comment: @user5341 I think the misunderstanding then is that it's not my responsibility to edit any particular question here. One comment pointed out the "steady" issue, and the next comment seemed to be a counterpoint that mentioned the claim did appear to be in the URLs. Since then, the question was edited in ways that all that nuance was lost - but that's not my concern. It's the community's content now, and the community's responsibility to do with it as the community sees fit. I got mine.

Comment: @Oddthinking - if someone sees an article titled "Darwin proven wrong", on an article discussing nuanced scientific paper discussing a specific theory posed by Darwin, would you really accept as substantive an answer "no, Darwin was not proven wrong, evolution still stands - here's Wiki article on evolution", instead of an answer "**No**, the claim is misrepresenting the actual finding, Darwin as a whole wasn't proven wrong  and nobody claims that. However, **yes**, one specific idea of his was, indeed, proven wrong - proof is in the actual article you used to base the claim on"

Comment: @Patrick87 - Typically, OP is deferred to as far as edits, as a matter of courtesy. Would YOU feel OK if I went in and edited the question now to ask about only steady paychecks?

Comment: @user5341 Why not? Somebody else did. Editing content is part of the SE model. Wouldn't you feel OK if I corrected an error in your post? If not - why use SE? Any random guy can edit "your" stuff right now.

Comment: @Patrick87 - I likely would feel OK (depends on the edit), BUT I'd feel much better if someone asked my OK to edit first. SE model de-jure encourages others to edit. SE model de-facto has a mild preference on letting OP do so, if feasible, at least on many sites, as a matter of courtesy.

Comment: @user5341 Is there a reference to support your assertion about the de facto model and to which sites it allegedly applies? I have used several sites and never encountered this sentiment before.

Comment: @Patrick87 - the most coherent I recall are various Meta policies on edit wars, most of which end up giving minor preference to OP in case an edit war erupts, unless there are good reasons. I suspect the rest is diffuse chat/comments vague culture thing, not something I recall being a formal policy.

Comment: @user5341 What point are you trying to make? There was no "edit war" here. Even if this "de facto" model is more than a flight of fancy, and you were extending a "courtesy" by calling my question a blatant straw man and demanding it be fixed, what's your argument now? That I acted improperly by not graciously accepting the courtesy quickly enough?